# Wicket - MarkupNotFoundException: Markup of type 'html' for component 'com.hello.Hello' not found

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff

I know it is a very basic topic but unfortunately I cannot figure it out why I am getting the above error message....
I am trying to generate a simple HelloWorld Wicket application but I keep getting a html markup error...

My code is the following:

**Hello class**

```
package com.hello;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

public class Hello extends WebPage {

    public Hello() {
        add(new Label("message", "Hello Wicket World"));
    }
}
```

**Hello html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:wicket="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wicket World, szevasztok!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <span wicket:id="message">message comes here</span>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyApplication class**

```
package com;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import com.hello.Hello;

public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return Hello.class;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
<display-name>Wicket Web Application</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>wicket</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>wicket</groupId>
<artifactId>WicketExample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WicketExample</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>WicketExample</finalName>

      <resources>
          <resource>
              <filtering>false</filtering>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
          <resource>
              <filtering>false</filtering>
              <directory>src/main/java</directory>
              <includes>
                  <include>*</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </resource>
      </resources>

      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <inherited>true</inherited>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                  <debug>true</debug>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

I receive the following error:

[image]

I have already googled for it, tried several refactoring, but I keep getting the same....

Any idea?

Sorry for this very basic topic.... :(

Comment: Are Java page class and html side by side in the same folder? Check for possible spelling errors, for example hello.html instead of Hello.html

Comment: @AndreaDelBene thanks for you answer! Yes, they are in the same folder and I cannot find any spelling error in my code... Any other idea?

Comment: How do you run your project? It looks like that the html file of your page is not copied in the build directory.

Comment: Why do you start a new project with Wicket 1.4.17 ? I recommend you to use latest 7.x or even 8.x. Or at least latest 1.4.x!

Comment: True, the html file  is missing from the war Meta-inf folder.... I just let "mvn compile war:war" run and deploy it to a payara server... how can i solve it?

Comment: haha, OK, I found the solution but have no clue what this setting has to do with the html packaging...
In the include tag I had only one star, with two it is now working....
<resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok to me, I guess the problem lies in your project structure which isn't entirely visible to me.

Since you're using maven anyway, why don't you just create a [Wicket Quickstart](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) project to get started? This generates you in zero time a working file structure with a decent pom.xml you can learn from:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeVersion=7.10.0 \
  -DgroupId=com.dorcsi.wicket \
  -DartifactId=hello \
  -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/ \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This stub project even contains an embedded jetty servlet conatiner, so you can run your application as simply as that:

```
    mvn jetty:run
```

Furthermore, as already stated by martin-g, there is not point starting a new project with wicket 1.4. The example above generates a wicket 7.10 project. As a matter of fact, I am using wicket 8 since the end of last year without any problems.